# Can I specify CSS media types in the style attribute?

Tags: css

I was wondering if I can specify any CSS media types in the style attribute? and what can I specify in the style attribute?

Comment: I am running into this same question now, specifically related to styling email in a way where we can hide certain things when the email is being printed out. Useful for invoices where we don't want all the details to be printed...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not that I know of. Your best bet is to define a `class` rather than inline styles. Then, you'll have more flexibility.

You can include different stylesheets by specifying the `media` attribute on your `link` tag to include a stylesheet, or you can also specify that rules within a stylesheet should only apply to a given media.

For example:

Including a CSS file by specifying a media:

```
<link media="print" href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Specifying a media within a stylesheet:

```
@media print
{
    .myStyle { display: none; } 
}
```

Also, see the [W3C media type list](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) for all your options.

Answer (score 3):

You can't specify media type, but you can specify whatever CSS properties the element will support.

Comment: Seriously, downvoter? This is accurate information and was the first answer given (therefore not copied from one of the others). In fact, the other answers, while more verbose, are in accord and might be construed as elaborations on this one.

Answer (score 1):

Media types is specific to style sheets only, per the w3 css specification:

> One of the most important features of
>   style sheets is that they specify how
>   a document is to be presented on
>   different media: on the screen, on
>   paper, with a speech synthesizer, with
>   a braille device, etc.

Ref:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/

The only thing that can be specified in the style attribute is property:value pairs for styling the specific element.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a `;` delimited list of `property: value` pairs. You can **not** include the media type.

99% of the time, you are better using an external stylesheet. I use `style` attribute mainly for animating the element via JavaScript. Occasionally I use the `style` to specify a background image (where it is dynamic and echo'd to the markup), where it would be too cumbersome to add a preprocessor to my raw CSS files.